# JavaScript jQuery appendTo and plugin work together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append an input markup

```
 $('<input type="text" placeholder="I have a placeholder!">').appendTo('.myclass');
```

the input field is fine, but placeholder plugin is not working. I use [Placeholders.js](http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/) plugin, So i have to use

```
setTimeout(function(){$('input').placeholder();},300)
```

to make it work.

I just wanted to make sure if this is a right way to make it work or there is a better method.

**Answer**

I found I should put `$('input').placeholder();` **after** `appendTo` not before.
Problem is resolved!
Thanks guys

Comment: if you add new elements, need to initalize plugin for them as you are doing. Shouldn't need the timeout if you call plugin right after append

Comment: i don't think theres anything bad in it but did you tried initializing the placeholder plugin directly after appending the input element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the DOM is synchronous, so you should be able to do this:

```
$('<input type="text" placeholder="I have a placeholder!">')
    .appendTo('.myclass')
    .placeholder();
```